# CPU fan stops when Windows starts

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, temperature

After I cleaned up its wings (I do it every several times a year), my (Fujitsu Lifebook ah530-10) laptop's Cpu fan stopped spinning when windows 10 start. It does spin while in BIOS pages and also until windows is loaded.

BIOS fan control is set to "normal" (options are quiet/normal).

SpeedFan reporting 50%-100% speed and 70-90C degrees.

Shorting the yellow wire to the red or black didnt make it spin.

Feeding 5V to the red wire and grounding the black makes it spin at full speed, so currently I`m using external power adapter to make it work.

Can it be a fan fault? (I already ordered a new one) The cpu temperature measures seems accurate in SpeedFan.

Its a 3 pin fan of the following model: [image: cpu fan]

Comment: Please advise the make and model of your laptop from the serial number plate underneath, and also the BIOS settings for fan control. Also, have you added any hardware control between the motherboard and fan? Please click [edit] and add the answers to your original question, as Comments can overflow and get hidden.

Comment: The Fan might be controlled by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation and the delivered power is not enough to start the fan.

Comment: @K7AAY info added to the question. Its a Fujitsu Lifebook ah530-10, bios fan mode is "normal" (options are quiet/normal). I didnt add or modified the hardware but since the fan stopped working im powering it with an external 5V adapter (as described in the original question).

Comment: Is the laptop actually overheating under Windows, or does the fan not run because the CPU is cool?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yes it does. 70-90C. Until this problem happened the fan was spinning constantly. When several browser tabs were opened it was spinning at 100%. Now It doesnt spin no matter what I do on windows.

Answer (score 0):

It's BIOS ver. issue. Download BIOS Flash (ISO CD-Image) - Lifebook A530 / AH530    1.19 (15/08/2011)
https://support.ts.fujitsu.com/IndexDownload.asp?SoftwareGuid=AECD2E9C-C0C9-4828-A06A-9F9655C603A6
Burn on CD. Boot form CD and type FLASH.
After it FAN working normal